# "NameError: uninitialized constant" on existing ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I get this error when running `rake db:seed` in my app: `NameError: uninitialized constant AdmissionEpisode::AdminDistrictId`.

I have no idea why - admission_episode.admin_district_id exists in the database and I have `belongs_to :admin_district` in the AdmissionEpisode model. Does anybody have any idea what's going on?

Here is the AdminDistrict seed:

```
districts.each do |code, name|
  AdminDistrict.create({
      code: code,
      name: name
    })
end
```

And this is the AdmissionEpisode seed (with the NameError occuring on the `AdmissionEpisode.create` line:

```
admissions.each do |code, total, male, female|
  district = AdminDistrict.find_by_code(code)

  AdmissionEpisode.create({
      admin_district_id: district.id,
      total: total,
      male: male,
      female: female
    })
end
```

`districts` and `admissions` as referenced above are both lists of data, all of which are, as far as I can tell, formatted correctly. The `admin_district` table is also populated correctly.

Comment: Does `AdmissionEpisode.create admin_district: district, # etc` work?

Comment: Do you have `admin_district_id` in `admission_episodes` table?

Comment: @Pavan: yes. @DVG: if I do that, I get this error instead, on the same line: `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'admin_district' for AdmissionEpisode`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm kicking myself.

The issue was that the models actually had `belongs_to :admin_district_id`, and once they were changed to `belongs_to :admin_district`, the issue was resolved.

I think the issue came about when generating the models - I must have used `admin_district_id:references` instead of the correct `admin_district:references`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can try this:

```
admissions.each do |code, total, male, female|
  district = AdminDistrict.find_by_code(code)

  district.admission_episodes.create({
    total: total,
    male: male,
    female: female
  })
end
```

Comment: Doing this, I get this error on the same line: `NoMethodError: undefined method `admission_episodes' for #<AdminDistrict:0x007f0f87a15430>`. It seems as though there's just no relation, but I'm dead sure that it's all correct!